# Ending, out of loop function not being called, adding run counts

Tags: powershell, scripting

So, I've got a long script with 8 functions. At the end, in the execution section I call those functions in ForEach loops, two of them. What I'm trying to do is call one of them after and outside of the loops.
The 5 `Log-Write` lines are what I'm talking about. Now if I run my script only the 5th line ends up in the logfile.  I'*know* my syntax is jacked up but I have no idea how to call the function in a summary fashion, at the very end of the script AFTER the loops have processed.

Here's the code:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------[Initializations]-------------------------------------------------------- 
 Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[Switch]$LogOnly
)

#  Dot Source required Function Libraries
#. "\\server\scripts\Logging_Functions.ps1" 
. "c:\users\documents\powershell\Functions\Logging_Functions.ps1"

#  Error Action
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
#  Debug preference
$global:DebugPreference = "continue"
#  WhatIf Preference, uncomment to run script in a logging only function
#$WhatIfPreference = $true

#----------------------------------------------------------[Declarations]----------------------------------------------------------
  
#  Script Version
$sScriptVersion = "1.0"

Import-Module ActiveDirectory


#  Log File Info
$sLogPath = "C:\Users\Documents\powershell\Logs"
#$sLogPath = "\\server\e$\Logs"
$sLogName = "Set-LitmosGroups_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss).log"
$sLogOnlyPath = "C:\Users\Documents\powershell\Logs"
$sLogOnlyName = "\Set-LitmosGroups (Log Only)_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss).log"
$sLogFile = Join-Path -Path $sLogPath -ChildPath $sLogName
$sLogOnlyFile = Join-Path -Path $sLogOnlyPath -ChildPath $sLogOnlyName
$LogLine = $null 

#$logonly = $null

#  Variable Initializations
#  Org Unit where the target groups reside (Litmos)
$OU = "ou=test_litmos, ou=test accounts, ou=domain, dc=net"
#  Org unt containing the All Managers security group
$OU2 = "CN=All Managers,OU=Organizational,OU=Groups,OU=domain,DC=net"

#  Get member of the 'ALL Managers' security group
$Managers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $OU2 | Select-Object -expandproperty samaccountname

#  Get AD groups with Report to in the name in $ou
$ReportsTo = Get-adgroup -searchbase $ou -filter "Name -like 'Report to *'" |  
Select-Object -expandproperty name

$samecount = 0
$addgroupcount = 0
$addusercount = 0
$LogOnlyAdduserCount = 0
$LogOnlyGroupCount = 0

#----------------------------------------------------------[Functions]-------------------------------------------------------------


Function Get-DirectReport {
    #requires -Module ActiveDirectory
 
   
 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $false,
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )]
 
        [string]  $SamAccountName,
 
        [switch]  $NoRecurse
    )
 
    BEGIN {}
 
    PROCESS {
        $UserAccount = Get-ADUser $SamAccountName -Properties DirectReports, DisplayName
        $UserAccount | select -ExpandProperty DirectReports | ForEach-Object {
            $User = Get-ADUser $_ -Properties DirectReports, DisplayName, Title, EmployeeID
            if ($null -ne $User.EmployeeID) {
                if (-not $NoRecurse) {
                    Get-DirectReport $User.SamAccountName
                }
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    SamAccountName    = $User.SamAccountName
                    UserPrincipalName = $User.UserPrincipalName
                    DisplayName       = $User.DisplayName
                    Manager           = $UserAccount.DisplayName
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    END {}
 
}

Function New-bhReportToGroup {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    $Log1 = "New group for " + $manager + " has been created."
    $Log2 = "Group for " + $manager + " already exists."
    #From on when you see the below line $script:<variable> that sets the scope for that variable to the entire script which means other functions can use the value
    $script:ReportsTo = $ReportsTo -replace ("Report to ", "")

    if ($manager -notin $ReportsTo) { 
        $LogLine = $Log1
        $addgroupcount = $addcount + 1
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $LogLine = $Log2
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}

Function New-bhReportToGroup_logonly {
    #[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    $Log1 = "New group for " + $manager + " would have been created in $OU."
    $Log2 = "Group for " + $manager + " already exists in $OU."
    $script:ReportsTo = $ReportsTo -replace ("Report to ", "")

    if ($manager -notin $ReportsTo) { 
        $Script:addcount = $addcount +1
        $LogLine = $Log1
        $LogOnlyGroupCount = $LogOnlyGroupCount + 1
        Log-Write -LogPath $LogOnlyFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }


    else {
        $Script:samecount = $samecount + 1
        $LogLine = $Log2
        Log-Write -LogPath $LogOnlyFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}

Function Get-bhDReports {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    $directreports = Get-Directreport $manager -norecurse  | Select-Object samAccountName
    if ($null -ne $directreports) {        
        $LogLine = "Gathering direct reports for " + $manager
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $LogLine = $manager + " has no reports."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }   
}

Function Set-bhRTGmembers {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    #  Get manager's 'report to <manager>' group again to update members
    $managerReportToGroup = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $OU -Filter "Name -like 'Report to $Manager'"
    $directreports = Get-Directreport $manager -norecurse  | Select-Object samAccountName
    if ($managerReportToGroup) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $managerReportToGroup.Name -members $DirectReports
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $managerReportToGroup.name -members $Manager
        $LogLine = "Report to " + $Manager + " updated."
        $Addusercount = $Addusercount +1
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $LogLine = "Could not find group for " + $Manager
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}

Function Set-bhRTGmembers_logonly {
    #  Get manager's 'report to <manager>' group again to update members
    $managerReportToGroup = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $OU -Filter "Name -like 'Report to $Manager'"
    if ($managerReportToGroup) {
        $LogOnlyAdduserCount = $LogOnlyAddUserCount +1
        $LogLine = "Report to " + $Manager + " would be updated with "+ $LogOnlyAddUserCount + " " + $DirectReports.name
        Log-Write -LogPath $LogOnlyFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $LogLine = "Could not find group for " + $Manager
        Log-Write -LogPath $LogOnlyFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}

Function Remove-bhOOSGroups {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    $report = $report -replace ("Report to ", "")
    if ($Report -notin $managers) {
        Remove-ADGroup -Identity "Report to $Report" -confirm:$false
        $LogLine = $report + " user has fell out of scope, Report group removed."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    }
    else {
       Continue
    }
}

Function Remove-bhOOSGroups_logonly {
    $report = $report -replace ("Report to ", "")
    if ($Report -notin $managers) {
        $LogLine = $report + " user has fell out of scope, Report group would be removed."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogOnlyFile -LineValue $LogLine
    }
    else {
       Continue
    }
}

#----------------------------------------------[ Execution ]------------------------------------------------


#Managers | Foreach-Object -Parallel {
Foreach ($Manager in $Managers) {
    if (-not $LogOnly) {
    $Directreports = Get-Directreport $manager -norecurse  | Select-Object -expand samAccountName
    Ttime = (Get-Date).ToString('T')
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $Manager + "'s" + "Direct reports are: " $Directreports
        New-bhReportToGroup
        Get-bhDReports
        Set-bhRTGmembers
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue "========================[$Time ]==============================="
        
 } else {
        New-bhReportToGroup_logonly
        Get-bhDReports
        Set-bhRTGmembers_logonly
        Log-Write -LogPath $LogOnlyFile -LineValue "========================[ LogOnly ]==============================="  
    }
  }
Foreach ($Report in $ReportsTo) {
    If (-not $LogOnly){
    Remove-bhOOSGroups
} else {
    #ForEach ($Report in $ReportsTo) {
    Remove-bhOOSGroups_logonly
        }
   }
#}

Log-Write -LogPath $sLogPath -Linevalue $addgroupcount + " New groups added"
Log-Write -Logpath $sLogPath -Linevalue $AddUserCount + " New users added to groups"
Log-Write -Logpath $sLogOnlyPath -Linevalue $LogOnlyAdduserCount + " Users who would be added"
Log-Write -Logpath $sLogOnlyPath -Linevalue $LogOnlyGroupCount + " Groups that would be added"
Log-Write -LogPath $sLogPath -Linevalue "====[END]====="
```

Comment: "only the 5th line ends up in the logfile" - that sounds more like a problem with the `Log-Write` function than with your script

Comment: you are using the $Var _names_ you defined in the beginning of your script ... but they are not in the same scope as the ones in your various function. for instance, the `$LogOnlyGroupCount` that you define at the start IS NOT the same one you use in `Function New-bhReportToGroup_logonly {`. you need to send those values back out OR use a scope modifier [nasty, icky].

Comment: @Lee_Dailey You found a problem I did not know I had yet. Bravo sir... I did sit here shortly wondering why I had all zeroes.

Comment: @Skeer - you are most welcome! very glad to have helped ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess since I cant see your Log-write function, but since only the 5th line works, I'd bet you could get the other lines to show up by passing a string to the linevalue parameter (by putting the whole line in double quotes so it takes the variable value).  Like so:

```
Log-Write -Logpath $sLogOnlyPath -Linevalue "$LogOnlyGroupCount Groups that would be added"
```

Comment: I as going to ask the 'why' but I believe the answer lies in the Log-Write function... as to why the format I used did not work here but works for `write-host`....

Comment: Wow sorry I read the wrong name somehow. Brilliant.